# Multithreading brute-force and recursive multidimensional loops. Another way?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, recursion, brute-force

I like figuring things out myself in terms of programming... So I was thinking of a method to loop through multi-dimensional arrays with dynamic dimensions. (mainly for things like brute force)

The method I came up with to loop through arrays of unknown dimensions is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* a simple example of the method I'm using */
void func(int *v,char *usable,int len,int D,int d)
{
  for(v[d] = 0; v[d] < len; v[d]++)
  {
    if(d+1 < D)
      func(v,len,D,d+1);
    else
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < D; i++)
        printf("%c",usable[v[i]]);
      printf("\r");
    }
  }
}
int main()
{
  int *v,z,min = 4,max = 6;
  for(z = min; z <= max; z++)
  {
    v = malloc(sizeof(int)*z);
    func(v,"0123456789",10,z,0);
    printf("\n");
    free(v);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I see this as a nice elegant solution but I've come up with more problems when thinking of multi-threading the process. I would like to know **alternate solutions** for this type of process that I haven't discovered, as well as **possible ways of multi-threading** a process like this. One method I tried was creating pre-determined *chunks* but because of the large amount of values that need to be processed when digits or usable characters increase are too big, they overflow any normal variables.

One might ask: "Why do you need to create a multithreading brute force." And I would reply that the ability to create a multithreaded brute force means the ability to multithread other processes like maze-solving and best-route determination.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still confused on what you are trying todo with your code. But from your description. You said you were trying to develope a "method to loop through multi-dimensional arrays with dynamic dimensions."

To me that statement says that you want to loop through a array of n-dimension. So it would loop through array[n] or loop through array[n][m] and so on for any number of dimension and length. Is this what you are trying todo? If so them you can simply use a templated function to loop through the n-dimensional array.

Comment: yes, you understand what I'm doing. And what you described is what my code does. However I'm looking for a way to multithread the process. That means I need to split the work up into multiple threads (hopefully relatively equal)

your method is reasonable-but I would like it to be compatible with C